# Git branch vs commit

Tags: git, branch, commit

I have a **master** branch to where I had commited my last change and then after I ran

```
git branch test
git checkout test
```

I deleted file **README** in the project folder

then I ran

```
git checkout master
```

Now there is no **README** file anymore.

I thought that when you create a new branch it's just like creating a new commit. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you actually commit in the `test` branch? Because if you didn't your changes would just have been lost when you went back to the `master` branch.

Comment: No i did not commit on test, changes was to delete README when i went back to master README was still not there.

Comment: `checkout test` means you never changed branch. `git checkout test`?

Comment: yes git checkout test...

Comment: elcanibal - changes not lost by switching to different branch before commiting, test it.

Comment: never mind my last comment its actually more complicated that that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a branch is not like creating a new commit. Creating a branch is like creating an easy to read reference to a commit hash.

So by being on the `master` branch and then going:

```
git branch test
git checkout test
rm README
git checkout master
```

You will still have unstaged changes on the `master` branch, because you didn't actually do anything to `test`.

If you do `git status` you should have README missing.

You can get it back by doing `git checkout README`.